# Copy part of json key-values in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Given a json like this

```
  var json1 = {
        "key1": {
          "index": "1",
          "value": null
        },
        "key2": {
          "index": "2",
          "value": null
        },
        "key3": {
          "index": "3",
          "value": null
      };

  var json2 = {
                "key3": {
                  "index": "3",
                  "value": "value3"
                },
                "key4": {
                  "index": "4",
                  "value": 'value4'
              }
        };
```

how to get a new json like this, it will only copy the same key to the first one.

```
json3= {
        "key1": {
          "index": "1",
          "value": null
        },
        "key2": {
          "index": "2",
          "value": null
        },
        "key3": {
          "index": "3",
          "value": 'value3'
      }
};
```

I've tried on `Object.assign`  or `_.assign` of lodash

```
 Object.assign(json1,json2)
 _.assign(json1,json2)
```

but it will copy all the objects of json2 to json1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` to get all the keys from `json1` then check if the key exist in `json2`,if it exists then get the value corresponding to that key from json2

```js
var json1 = {
  "key1": {
    "index": "1",
    "value": null
  },
  "key2": {
    "index": "2",
    "value": null
  },
  "key3": {
    "index": "3",
    "value": null
  }
}

var json2 = {
  "key3": {
    "index": "3",
    "value": "value3"
  },
  "key4": {
    "index": "4",
    "value": 'value4'
  }
};

Object.keys(json1).forEach((item) => {
  if (json2.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    json1[item].value = json2[item].value
  }
})
console.log(json1)
```

Comment: Thanks! If each key's depth in json1 and json2 be uncertain, is it possible to get a recursive function to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const json1 = {
    "key1": {
      "index": "1",
      "value": null
    },
    "key2": {
      "index": "2",
      "value": null
    },
    "key3": {
      "index": "3",
      "value": null
  }
};

const json2 = {
        "key3": {
          "index": "3",
          "value": "value3"
        },
        "key4": {
          "index": "4",
          "value": 'value4'
      }
};

const result = {};
for(const key in json1) {
  result[key] = json2[key] ? json2[key] : json1[key];
};

console.log(result);
```

You can use a `for in` for it.

Answer (score 0):

Live Demo: https://runkit.com/embed/0z916nnwl2w5

```
var output = Object.assign(json1,json2);
delete output.key4;  //Here is the key~~~
console.log(output);
```

[image]

Comment: boo. this does what he wants, but its not realistic because it will required a code change if json2 has key5. basically he wants the diff(1 & 2) + instersection(1 &2): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript/11353526